# Cannot read property id of null , When i refresh the page i get this error

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
router.get("/:category/:product",(req,res,next)=>{

 var galleryImages=null;
     Products.findOne({title:req.params.product},function(err,product){

         if(err){
             console.log(err)
         }else{
             var galleryDir="public/dyqani/product_images/"+product._id+"/gallery";
             fs.readdir(galleryDir,function(err,files){
         if(err){
             console.log(err)
         }else{
                 galleryImages=files;
                 res.render("./dyqani/store/products",{
                 title:product.title,
                 p:product,
                 galleryImages:galleryImages
             });
             }
     });
     }
     });
});
```

When i try to open the page it shows me this error : Cannot read property _id of null , please any help ?
 When i make 
        console.log(product);

{ flavour: [ 5adafbff2eb0e211107c737b ],
  _id: 5ada72c56c0beb1c58c307f0,
  title: 'sss',
  slug: 'sss',
  desc: 'PURITY ABOVE ALL\r\n\r\nIso Whey ZERO is made with the purest cross-flow micro filtered whey protein isolate (WPI) possible, while it truly contains ZERO lactose, ZERO trans fat and ZERO added sugar. Iso Whey ZERO, like all BioTechUSA products, consists of 100% safe, carefully selected nutrients.\r\n\r\nSome like it lean\r\n\r\nThe extremely high biological value of proteins makes Iso Whey ZERO absolutely unique in the BioTech USA product line. It\'s perfect for athletes who aim for ultra-lean muscle gains as proteins contribute to muscle mass growth and muscle maintenance.\r\n\r\nWhen we say ZERO we mean ZERO\r\n\r\nIt’s true: Iso Whey ZERO contains ZERO trans fat and ZERO added sugar. No useless or hidden nutrients that could be stored by the body as fat. Only 22 g of pure muscle building protein in each serving.\r\n\r\nHigh BCAA, L-Glutamine, EAAs\r\n\r\nManufactured with carefully selected protein sources, the amino profile of Iso Whey ZERO is perfect for real muscle gains. It is high in BCAAs and EAAs (essential amino acids) as well as L-Glutamine, the most important amino acids aiming to build lean muscle mass',
  price: 70,
  category: 'preworkout',
  image: 'motivation4.jpg',
  __v: 1 }

null

events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of null
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\mm\bb\routes\dyqani\products.js:54:53
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\mm\bb\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3949:16
    at Immediate. (C:\Users\User\Desktop\mm\bb\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1516:14)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\User\Desktop\mm\bb\node_modules\mquery\lib\utils.js:119:16)
    at runCallback (timers.js:789:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:751:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:722:5)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting..

Comment: `console.log(product)` prints what ?

Comment: That prints the object and after the object prints null ;

Comment: So prints to things first is the object and then prints null and then show me the error

Comment: I have shown it in the question ? Any help please? thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line:

```
var galleryDir="public/dyqani/product_images/"+product._id+"/gallery";
```

The variable `product` is null because your query `Products.findOne({title:req.params.product}` is returning null.

Check if `req.params.product` contains any value and if in the database exists a tuple of a Product which the id is equal to the param.

Comment: Hello , the problem is that for the first time when i open the page its okay the Products.findOne({title:req.params.product} is returnin an object but after that show me that error ? any help ?